# web3.eth.subscribe not working properly

Tags: web3js, events, event-handling

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
    
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("url"));
    const addr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress("0x000080383847bD75F91c168269Aa74004877592f")
    const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe("logs", {
        address: addr,
        fromBlock: 31220000,
      }
      , function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Error subscribing to events: ", error);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully subscribed to events: ", result);
        }
      }
      )
      .on("connected", function (subscriptionId) {
        console.log("Connected to events: ", subscriptionId);
      })
      .on("data", function (log) {
        console.log("Received event data: ", log);
      })
      .on("error", function (error) {
        console.error("Error receiving event data: ", error);
      })
      .on("changed", function (log) {
        console.log("Event data changed: ", log);
      });
    console.log(subscription.on("connected",async (subscriptionId)=>{
        console.log("=================================================");
        console.log(subscriptionId);
        
    }));
    
    // unsubscribes the subscription
    subscription.unsubscribe(function (error, success) {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error unsubscribing: ", error);
      } else if (success) {
        console.log("Successfully unsubscribed!");
      }
    });
```

Here none of the subscription.on() is working whether it's connected ,data, changed or error. I have checked the blastapi for websocket and that is working fine too. what is wrong here becoz inorder for this to work i need to know whether the socket is connected or not or if there are partial breaks.

Comment: seems it is possible for the subscription to get unsubscribe here, can you add the executing functions separately?

Comment: actually i got it working. there was no problem with the code, it was working after a few hours on its own. i tried to recreate the error but cudn't yet